# Why do i keep getting a null reference error using RecyclerView with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im using fragments for my application. Im also using a nagivation drawer that opens the fragments via buttons in the drawer.

Im trying to display some basic images and texts for my recyclerview with its adapter and arraylist.

The problem i am having is that i dont know how to amend the code to use recyclerview to my fragments as all the tutorials ive seen do not use fragments.

Below is my activity code:

```
public class secondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    ArrayList<exampleItemBooks> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.artofwar, "Line 1", "Line 
    2"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.aristotle, "Line 3", 
    "Line 4"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.caesarbook, "Line 5", 
    "Line 6"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.platorepublic, "Line 7", 
    "Line 8"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.senecaletters, "Line 9", 
    "Line 10"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.thehistoryofmypeople, 
    "Line 11", "Line 12"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.theprince, "Line 13", 
    "Line 14"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.thritysixstrategems, 
    "Line 15", "Line 16"));
    exampleList.add(new exampleItemBooks(R.drawable.medidations, "Line 17", 
    "Line 18"));

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBooks);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new exampleBooksAdapter(exampleList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, 
    toolbar, R.string.navigation_open_drawer, 
    R.string.navigation_close_drawer);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
        //Set the button as checked.
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);

    }
}
```

Below is my fragment class code that is responsible for my fragment that i am using the recyclerview for:

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
   import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class BooksFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBooks);
        //mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBooks);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;

    }
}
```

Below is my adapter for the recyclerView:

```
   public class exampleBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<exampleBooksAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<exampleItemBooks> mExampleList;

    public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewCards);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard1);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard2);
        }
    }

    public exampleBooksAdapter(ArrayList<exampleItemBooks> exampleItemBooks) {

        mExampleList = exampleItemBooks;

    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item_books, parent, false);
        ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
        return evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        exampleItemBooks currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mExampleList.size();
    }
}
```

Below is my arraylist class:

```
 public class exampleItemBooks {

    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;

    public exampleItemBooks(int imageResource, String text1, String text2) {

        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;

    }

    public int getImageResource() {

        return mImageResource;

    }

    public String getText1() {

        return mText1;
    }

    public String getText2() {

        return mText2;
    }

}
```

And the error i keep getting is this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.warstories, PID: 5753
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.warstories/com.example.warstories.secondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.warstories.secondActivity.onCreate(secondActivity.java:42)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Key error desc:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.warstories/com.example.warstories.secondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference.

Any help?

Comment: If your Fragment owns the `RecyclerView`, why does the Activity do anything with it at all (vs the Fragment having all that code)? If the Activity needs to know about the RecyclerView, why do you have a Fragment at all? I think you need to pick one of the two, not both.

Comment: In order to inflate two different layouts, i needed to create a new fragment class. However, im not sure if this class is being used at all since the problem lies in the activity class. Its just not finding the recyclerview via findViewById. I heard that i need to put this code in my fragment class but it ends in error too.

Comment: Why do you have two layouts at all?

Comment: I am using a drawer nagivation layout which is not in the same xml file as with the other fragment. In other words, the fragment is not in my main xml file which is used to inflate the mainactivity screen. I dont know if i can use just one layout and have both my layouts on screen...

Comment: `mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard2);` <-- that should be `mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCard2);`

Comment: But it sounds like `recyclerViewBooks` doesn't exist in `second_activity.xml` (layout).

Comment: It doesnt. It exists in the fragment_books layout and this layout is used in the BooksFragment class which is why i have two layouts and i am using fragments.I dont know what code or where to put the code as im very new to fragments and android development. I dont think the problem is with the itemView. Its to do with the layoutManager. Im calling the recyclerView in a layout that it does not exist but i dont know how to modify it so the code is in the right activity/fragment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is failing because your Activity is trying to access the `RecyclerView` that is part of the Fragment's layout and your Fragment's layout isn't available immediately after you call `setContentView()` (even after your `replace()` operation, it is only asynchronously available since you use `commit()` instead of `commitNow()`).

Fragments should be (to as much of an extent as possible) **self-contained**. That means that if your Fragment owns the `RecyclerView`, it should be responsible for loading data into it: not your Activity.

You should move all of the code that is in your Activity that touches the `RecyclerView` to the Fragment - ideally, into a method such as `onViewCreated()`, which gives you access to the View you've inflated in `onCreateView()` and is the appropriate place to call `findViewById()` and get your `RecyclerView`.

Comment: including the arraylist on my main activity? So, i will create an onViewCreated method and put all the related code in there. Does the arraylist go inside this too? Also, i will put the code: mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBooks); into this method also. Is this correct?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could modify my code here to show me how to do it :)

Comment: Yep, everything having to do with the `RecyclerView`, including the `ArrayList` you use to fill the `RecyclerView`.